# A $m$-dimensional block $B$ belongs to the partition $P+Q$ $\iff$ is the intersection of a block of $P$ with a block of $Q$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying multiple integrals and we have the concept of m-dimensional blocks as being the set

$$\Pi_{1}^{m}[a_i, b_i]\subset \mathbb{R}^m$$

There's the following exercise:

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be partitions of the $m$-dimensional block $A$. A
>   $m$-dimensional block $B$ belongs to the partition $P+Q$ $\iff$ is the
>   intersection of a block of $P$ with a block of $Q$

The partition $P+Q$ is the union of $P$ and $Q$. This exercise is kinda weird because there's a mention of $A$ and then it's not used anymore.

For $\leftarrow$, Is $B = C\cap (P+Q)$ for some block $C$?

Comment: Perhaps if you added some of your work so far, you could get a good answer

Comment: You're right, generally I put my work here, but it mentions $A$ and does not even use it after.

Comment: But A is just the big block you are working with, which you then partition by P and Q. Then $B\in A$. That’s where A comes in.